# MooTools onLoad SmoothScrolling (Lim Chee Aun Method)

Tags: javascript, mootools, smooth-scrolling

From the post Lim Chee Un made here:
http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-onload-smoothscroll

```
window.addEvent(‘domready’, function() {
new SmoothScroll({ duration:700 }, window);
var el = window.location.hash.substring(1); // the hash
if(el) {
window.scrollTo(0,0);
var scroll = new Fx.Scroll(window, { wait: false, duration: 700, transition: Fx.Transitions.Quad.easeInOut });
scroll.toElement(el);
}
});
```

I would like to have the page automatically smooth scroll to the # in the URL when the page loads.

Smooth scrolling works when the link is like this, ie same page:

```
<a href="#pageHeading">Books & Booklets</a>
```

Rather than how I need it like this:

```
<a href="books.html#pageHeading">Books & Booklets</a>
```

Can anybody shed some light on why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Remove "without PHP" words in title, never heard of someone smooth scrolling a browser using server side script (unless you want maybe to smooth scroll the server's broswer, :) )

Comment: Hmmm I know what you are saying but have you looked at the code here? http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-onload-smoothscroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lim Chee Aun was kind enough to post up a solution!

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VqHf7/1/show/light/#about)

[Full Code](http://jsfiddle.net/VqHf7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the same javascript also in "books.html" page?

If not you need to place your script in there and in every page you want the smooth scroll to happen on page load.